# Override or Extend the closure function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, overriding

Just wondering about overriding the closure functions behavior.

e.g. How can i override the **baz()** function in below snippet?

```
(function() {
  var foo = 'Hello';
  var bar = 'World!'

  function baz(){
    return foo + ' ' + bar;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Do you want to edit the above closure to achieve something? Or do you want to modify it from outside that code?

Comment: As the name implies "closure" is something closed. You cannot access anything inside it from outside. You can do some tricks by adding a global variable which gives access to functions and variables, but that is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

If you are outside the closure, you cannot override the `baz()` function that is inside the closure.  Closures provide privacy and that works for local functions like it works for local variables.

If you are inside the closure, you can define a new version of `baz()` inside the closure or edit the code inside of `baz()`.

Related question: [Can I "extend" a closure-defined "class" in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561177/can-i-extend-a-closure-defined-class-in-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But what are advantages of using closure in this way?

What if i am using some external library and that library is written in that way(using closure functions), and i have to override/extend some of the functionality?

Comment: The library writer writes code this way because it allows them to create variables they can use that are not global variables (so they don't pollute the global namespace or conflict with anything else), but are available to their code and because it makes them private so they cannot be modified by outside agents.

Comment: So, what would the approach be to extend the functionality of that library. Adding custom logic in that particular library is not a good thing to do because when you upgrade it to a newer version you will lose your custom work.