# How to override methods in function based component React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Overriding is working the parent component is class based component

```
// Parent Button Class
class Button extends React.Component {
  createLabel = () => {
    return <span>{this.props.label}</span>;
  };
  render() {
    return <button>{this.createLabel()}</button>;
  }
}

//child Button class
class CustomButton extends Button {
  // Over Riding createLabel Function
  createLabel = () => {
    const { label, icon } = this.props;
    return <span>{icon ? icon : "" + label}</span>;
  };
}

function Test(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomButton label={"Save"} icon={"pi pi-loading"} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

I need help how to implement my CustomButton Component when the parent Button is function based component Like Below.

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const createLabel = () => {
    if (props.label) {
      return <span>{props.label}</span>;
    }
  };
  return <button>{createLabel()}</button>;
};
```

is that possible to override methods of function based component?

Comment: In React **composition** is preferred over inheritance. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: So, if you need to achieve _dynamic_ children, you might want to look at [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) or [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the response @YevhenHorbunkov, is that possible to do from inheritance, because my main parent component is from a different library

Comment: You cannot use inheritance with methods defined in a closure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259137/override-or-extend-the-closure-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use composition over inheritence. The original button can take a label as a callback:

```
// Basic button
function Button({createLabel}) {
  return <button>{createLabel()}</button>;
}
```

Then you can easily create wrappers for specific situations:

```
function CustomButton({label, icon}) {
  // Use a specific createLabel function
  return <Button 
      createLabel = {() => {
         // this function has direct access to props
         return <span>{icon ? icon : "" + label}</span>;
      }}
  />;
}
```

This is the version closest to what you have. However, you can also just pass the `<span>` directly as a prop, or use `children` to place it inside the component. Or use `useCallback` to make the callback more efficient. Many more improvements possible.

Comment: Thanks for response @mousetail , actually my parent component is from a library, so the implementation of parent i can't change, my code look like this 
`
import {Button } from "module/button" 

  class CustomButton extends Button {
  // Over Riding createLabel Function
  createLabel = () => {
    const { label, icon } = this.props;
    return <span>{icon ? icon : "" + label}</span>;
  };
}

function Test(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomButton label={"Save"} icon={"pi pi-loading"} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
`

Comment: So your parent component is a class and you want to override it as a function? That's not possible