# How can I extend a class defined behind a closure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of JavaScript "classes" where a base class defines functions that are then shared by an inherited class. It is working, and it is set up like this:

```
var ThingA = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

ThingA.prototype = {
    sayHi: function() {
        alert('Hi, ' + this.name + '!');
    }
};


var ThingB = function() {
    ThingA.call(this, 'Charlie');
};

ThingB.prototype = new ThingA();
ThingB.prototype.constructor = ThingB;

var instanceOfB = new ThingB();
instanceOfB.sayHi();   // alerts 'Hi, Charlie!'
```

For reasons that are outside of my control, my company prefers to follow this pattern when writing JavaScript:

```
SomeClass = function() {

    // "Private" functions go here

    function somePrivateMethod() { 
        ...
    }

    return {

        // "Public" methods go here
        somePublicMethod: function() { ... }

    };
}();
```

Now, this is fine as far as things go, and it works well for many situations. But it is more of a functional style. There is only one "class" instance, and everything is static.

I've been asked to modify my working code to more closely match the style my company prefers. So my question is, there a way to inherit from a class that is wrapped inside a factory class? It would look something like this:

```
FactoryClassA = function() {

    var ThingA = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };

    ThingA.prototype = {
        sayHi: function() {
            alert('Hi, ' + this.name + '!');
        }
    };

    return {
         createThingA: function(name) {
             return new ThingA(name);
         }
    };
}();


FactoryClassB = function() {

    // Define a ThingB class that inherits from ThingA somehow

    return {
         createThingB: function() {
             return new ThingB();
         }
    };
}();


var instanceOfB = FactoryClassB.createThingB();
instanceOfB.sayHi();   // should alert 'Hi, Charlie!'
```

**Is there a way to define `ThingB` wrapped in `FactoryClassB` that inherits from `ThingA` wrapped in `FactoryClassA`?**  Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561177/can-i-extend-a-closure-defined-class-in-javascript), I know that I'm not going to be able to do it exactly like this. I am thinking of using a method to extend a given class ... somehow?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561257/645511) seems close, but I'm having trouble figuring out the details of how to modify that example to fit with the specifics of my situation. I am willing to bend my company's usual pattern a little bit, but can I at least get closer to it?

**UPDATE 1**

In response to Adam's comment to just add a parameter to the factory class, here's where I'm stuck:

```
ThingB.prototype = new ThingA();
ThingB.prototype.constructor = ThingB;
```

I can't figure out how to adapt these lines to make it work if I just pass in a parameter to the factory class method.

Comment: The code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/v578n/

Comment: `FactoryClass A`'s definition ends with `();` see `FactoryClass A{...}()`. Is it a function or an object?

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I couldn't test that, because the FactoryClass example doesn't actually work yet -- it is what I am trying to get to work. Let me update that...

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please be nice in the comments. Non-constructive comments will be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is what (I believe) you're looking for:

```
FactoryClassA = function() {
    var ThingA = function(name) {
       this.name = name;
    };
    ThingA.prototype = {
        sayHi: function() {
            console.log('Hi, ' + this.name + '!');
        }
    };
    // Add the constructor back to the prototype
    // (see explanation below)
    ThingA.prototype.constructor = ThingA;

    return {
        createThingA: function(name) {
            return new ThingA(name);
        }
    };
}();

FactoryClassB = function() {
    // Bootstrapping:
    // Capture the instance, as we'll need it to set up the prototype
    var baseInstance = new FactoryClassA.createThingA();
    // Capture the constructor
    var baseConstructor = baseInstance.constructor;
    // Keep a reference to the base prototype
    var baseProto = baseConstructor.prototype;

    function ThingB(name) {
        // Call base constructor, along with our args
        baseConstructor.call(this, name);
    };
    ThingB.prototype = baseInstance;
    ThingB.prototype.constructor = ThingB;

    ThingB.prototype.sayHi = function() {
        console.log('here I am');
        // call the base class `sayHi`
        baseProto.sayHi.call(this);
    };

    return {
        createThingB: function(name) {
            return new ThingB(name);
        }
    };
}();

// Testing
var foo = FactoryClassB.createThingB("Indeed");
foo.sayHi();

// Output:
//   here I am 
//   hi indeed
```

**Explanation**:

in `FactoryClassA`, this line is necessary:

```
ThingA.prototype.constructor = ThingA;
```

Note that every prototype in JS is automatically created with a reference to its constructor.  For example, when you do:

```
function T(){}
```

`T.prototype` already has a property called `constructor` which points back to `T`.

However, in your implementation of `ThingA`, you reset the entire prototype, by doing `ThingA.prototype = { ... }`.  Therefore, **you now have lost the reference to its constructor**. In 99% of cases it is ok, and won't have any negative side effects (which is probably why most developers tend to forget it).  However, in the case of inheritance, it may be necessary.

Now, within `FactoryClassB`, we need to do some bootstrapping:

```
var baseInstance = new FactoryClassA.createThingA();
var baseConstructor = baseInstance.constructor;
var baseProto = baseConstructor.prototype;
```

Observe the last two lines, as they are pivotal to achieving inheritance in this design pattern.  First, since `ThingA`'s constructor is accessible via the prototype (`ThingA.prototype.constructor = ThingA`), then it means that given an instance of `ThingA`, we can directly retrieve its constructor. Since the constructor is the function itself, and since every function has a reference to its prototype, we can keep a reference of `ThingA.prototype` with `baseConstructor.prototype`.

Next is the critical part, where we set up the inheritance chain:

```
function ThingB(name) {
    // Call the base constructor
    baseConstructor.call(this, name);
};
ThingB.prototype = baseInstance;
ThingB.prototype.constructor = ThingB;
```

The last line above is quite important, as it tells the prototype what its constructor is, otherwise it would still point to `ThingA`.

There you have it - prototypal inheritance.

**Side note**:

You can probably see how the above can get quite tedious, a little grotesque, and repetitive.  Ergo, you might want to consider an inheritance library like [Fiber.js](https://github.com/linkedin/Fiber) which follows the encapsulation pattern you desired (along with some bonuses like mixins and decorators).  *Disclaimer: I authored the library*.

Comment: That is a great explanation. I had gotten *so close* to that solution, and yet was missing several key points. Thank you so much!